# Is it possible to restrict access for a Salesforce licensed user to only access Communities

Tags: community, employee-community

Is it possible to prevent a Salesforce Community Member (all Salesforce licenses including Chatter Free and Chatter Only) from accessing their internal organization?

When the user logs in, the global header shows all of the communities which they have access to as well as the link back to their internal organization. I would like to prevent some users from navigating out of the communities interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify, you want specific Salesforce User(s) with any license, to not access the internal org, but only have login access to the Community?

Comment: Correct. I want to use a Salesforce licensed user and keep them out of the internal org. This could be as simple as removing the link within the global header to make it slightly more difficult to navigate there.

Comment: Mark, global header can be given to users via profile or permission set. The permission set will give you more specific control over who can access the Communities URL. Additionally, you could always remove the Members profile or permission set to access the Community Under Workspaces -> Administration ->Members. This controls exactly who can get into the community. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. You need to De-activate the Salesforce License user and create another with the Community (Customer or Partner) license.

You cant reuse the UserName if the deactivated user have it. The change will be transparent for the user